# Highlight for emphasis

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Right now *to emphasize text* **we have** ***three options***.

Sometimes a little bit of controlled background-color might help to break large answers out into sections. [For example, in this answer I'm talking about two distinct things](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18901/can-someone-explain-the-reasons-for-the-implications-of-colum-vs-row-major-in/37185#37185), and I've interleaved the discussion.  I think a bit of color highlighting would help to make the answer more clear:

[image]

It wouldn't be an all out *color wheel*.  But I actually had in mind **one** highlight color (based on site theme) that could be used.  So on meta, it would be some light colored variation of (108,0,0) (crimson)

Comment: I like this in theory, but people can't even manage to use bold or italics sensibly right now.

Comment: ...let alone marking things as code when they are obviously not.